# Take the length of the xpath

Tags: xpath

I have a list which I can take their values using the following xpaths:

```
.//*[@id='LayoutWrapper']/div[6]/div[3]/main/section[3]/div/div/div[1]/xpl-result/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/span
.//*[@id='LayoutWrapper']/div[6]/div[3]/main/section[3]/div/div/div[2]/xpl-result/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/span
.//*[@id='LayoutWrapper']/div[6]/div[3]/main/section[3]/div/div/div[3]/xpl-result/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/span
.//*[@id='LayoutWrapper']/div[6]/div[3]/main/section[3]/div/div/div[4]/xpl-result/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/span
```

is it possible to use a xpath command to take the total number of list which is in the previous case in 4?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The number of items selected by an XPath expression, *xp*, is given by `count(xp)`.